# Recognize keystrokes using getch() [AT&T C++ 2.1]

Tags: c++, input, game-development, turbo-c++

I am making a C++ program on C++ 2.1 (Yeah the one that uses `iostream.h`) on Turbo C++. I am forced to use such an old software that works on DOS because I am supposed to use it for a school project (SORRY). The question is, I am forced to use `getch()` from `conio.h` as a method for detecting keystrokes as I am oblivious for other methods. Sadly, I recognizes one key at a time, making it impossible to recognize multi-key strokes (I am trying to develop a multiplayer single-keyboard game). Please help me and tell me if there is a way of achieving the desired functionality in my obsolete version of C++. Thanks in advance.

Link to the [code](https://gist.github.com/ryzokuken/8f526914fd66e4d714a4) (Input related functions are in `input.h` file)

Comment: Quit the school/class.  There is no reason any school should have you working one something that isn't even standard.  That is a disservice to you and all of the other students.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for the suggestion